# Firebase core cannot be imported in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I install firebase core. When I try to import it, I get an error that the target URI does not exist. How can I resolve this?

I tried importing the package like this: import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

I also tried to use different versions of the package, but same result.

Comment: make sure add the the dependency on pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command from your IDE's terminal/command prompt:

```
flutter pub add firebase_core
```

The above command will add firebase package to your pubspec.yaml file.
Next, you have to download the package to your project so run the following command:

```
flutter pub get
```

Now you can import the package with `import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'`

Comment: I already tried that some time ago, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by adding this in the dependencies field in the pubspec.yaml file :

firebase_core:
git:
url: 'https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire.git'
path: 'packages/firebase_core/firebase_core'